# How to fetch second value in string based on the matched value before the delimeter "|"?

Tags: php, regex

How to fetch second value in string based on the matched value before the delimeter "|"?

Desired Output:

```
12348888
113336669998888
```

Based on the searchfor value: `1254698`

```
<?php

        $contents = '12345|BHKAHHHHkk
1254698|12348888
12345|BHKNe22223366
1254698|113336669998888
012250000|22154545488888';

    $searchfor = '1254698';
    
    if(preg_match('/(?:\n|^)' . $searchfor .  '\|([^|]+)(.*?)(?:\r?\n|$)/is', $contents, $matchs))
    {
        $second_value = $matchs[1];
        $reset_values = $matchs[2];
        echo "Result for searching <b>$searchfor</b> is <b>$second_value</b> and reset of data is <b>$reset_values</b>";
    }
    else echo('Not Found :(');
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
<?php

$contents = '12345|BHKAHHHHkk
1254698|12348888
12345|BHKNe22223366
1254698|113336669998888
012250000|22154545488888';

$searchfor = '1254698';
    
if(preg_match_all('/^' . $searchfor .  '\|([^|\r\n]+)/m', $contents, $matchs))
{
    print_r($matchs[1]);
} else {
    echo('Not Found :(');
}
```

See the [online PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/V8m3Y). Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12348888
    [1] => 113336669998888
)
```

The regex is `/^$searchfor\|([^|\r\n]+)/m`, note the `m` flag that makes `^` match start of any line. The pattern matches

- `^` - start of a line
- `$searchfor` - the searched value
- `\|` - a literal `|` char
- `([^|\r\n]+)` - one or more chars other than `|`, CR and LF chars.

See the **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OcjKZG/1)**. Also, when testing at regex101.com, you can always use the

[image]

link to get the code generated for you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regexp, use a loop and split each line at `|` characters.

```
$lines = file($input_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINE)
$found = false;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    [$first_value, $second_value, $reset_values] = explode('|', $line, 3);
    if ($cols[0] == $searchfor) {
        echo "Result for searching <b>$searchfor</b> is <b>$second_value</b> and reset of data is <b>$reset_values</b>";
        $found = true;
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    echo 'Not Found :(';
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried running the code, I am getting undefined array errors on line: [$first_value, $second_value, $reset_values] = explode('|', $line, 3);

Comment: Do you have any blank lines? Add the `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` flag.

Comment: What version of PHP? You might need to write `list($first_value, $second_value, $reset_values) = ...`

Comment: i am using php 7.3

Comment: Then it's probably empty lines, add that flag: `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINE | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`